# Can an uploaded image be loaded directly by cv2?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I have an uploaded file in memory.  I want to manipulate the file with cv2.  Currently, I write the file to disk then read it with cv2.  How can I skip writing the file and load it directly with cv2?

```
file = request.files['file']
# if file and allowed_file(file.filename):

# save file            
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
file_path = os.path.join(dressrank.config['SHOW_IMG_FOLDER'], filename);
file.save(file_path)
img_path = file_path

# COLOR FATURE EXTRACTION
img = read_img(img_path)
img =img_resize(img, 500)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Build a numpy array using the uploaded data. Decode this array using cv2.

```
img = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromstring(request.files['file'].read(), numpy.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

---

[Prior to OpenCV 3.0, use `cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED` instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32596174)

---

See also: [Python OpenCV load image from byte string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17170752/400617)

Answer (score 3):

If working with BaseHTTPRequestHandler, one should first create a `FieldStorage` form:

```
fm = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=self.rfile, headers=self.headers, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST'})
```

then:

```
if "file" in fm:            
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(fm['file'].file.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Also, note that `fromstring` is deprecated, and that's why I'm updating davidism's answer with `frombuffer`.